# Invoking all setters within a class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

I have a domain object, that for the purposes of this question I will call Person with the following private variables:

```
String name
int age
```

Each of these have getters and setters. Now I also have a `Map<String, String>` with the following entries:

```
name, phil
age, 35
```

I would like to populate a list of all setter methods within the class Person and then looping through this list and invoking each method using the values from the map.

Is this even possible as I cannot see any examples close to this on the net. Examples are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure it's possible!  You can get all methods that start with "set" back by doing this:

```
Class curClass = myclass.class;
Method[] allMethods = curClass.getMethods();
List<Method> setters = new ArrayList<Method>();
for(Method method : allMethods) {
    if(method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
        setters.add(method);
    }
}
```

Now you've got the methods.  Do you already know how to call them for your instance of the class?

Comment: Hey, no problem.  Do you have any other questions?  If not, could you mark one of the answers as accepted?

Comment: @Krrose27 - getMethods() seems to also return inherited public methods, from javadoc: "getMethods - Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public member methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces."

Comment: Instead of using getMethods() use getDeclaredMethods() if you don't want inherited methods in your list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`BeanUtils.populate()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29)) from [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/)?

```
BeanUtils.populate(yourObject, propertiesMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a full solution that verifies output class beforehand and consequently calls setters for all the properties that the map contains. It uses purely `java.beans` and `java.lang.reflect`.

```
public Object mapToObject(Map<String, Object> input, Class<?> outputType) {
    Object outputObject = null;
    List<PropertyDescriptor> outputPropertyDescriptors = null;
    // Test if class is instantiable with default constructor
    if(isInstantiable(outputType) 
            && hasDefaultConstructor(outputType)
            && (outputPropertyDescriptors = getPropertyDescriptors(outputType)) != null) {
        try {
            outputObject = outputType.getConstructor().newInstance();
            for(PropertyDescriptor pd : outputPropertyDescriptors) {
                Object value = input.get(pd.getName());
                if(value != null) {
                    pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(outputObject, value);
                }
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException|IllegalAccessException|InvocationTargetException|NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to instantiate verified class " + outputType, e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specified outputType class " + outputType + "cannot be instantiated with default constructor!");
    }
    return outputObject;
}

private List<PropertyDescriptor> getPropertyDescriptors(Class<?> outputType) {
    List<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = null;
    try {
        propertyDescriptors = Arrays.asList(Introspector.getBeanInfo(outputType, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors());
    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    }
    return propertyDescriptors;
}

private boolean isInstantiable(Class<?> clazz) {
    return ! clazz.isInterface() && ! Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers());
}

private boolean hasDefaultConstructor(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        clazz.getConstructor();
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a library, the [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). If you have a map that contains field and value pairs, the class [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) can help you:

```
Person person = new Person();
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(person, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```